# WPF RadioButtons in details UserControl unchecked when navigating through parent ListView

Tags: wpf

---edited to include full code sample---

I know there have been a lot of issues with the .NET 3.5 RadioButton, but I believe this is a different issue that I have not found anything on in my searching. I've put together a very minimal code sample to demonstrate the problem I'm observing.

I have a ListView in my XAML that has its SelectedItem bound to the SelectedModel in my ViewModel. This same XAML contains a StackPanel that shows RadioButton options for the SelectedModel when navigating through items in the ListView. Everything works great until I add a RadioButton group into the mix. Now, if I select a record in the ListView that has one of the RadioButton options checked, then select another record in the ListView that has a different option checked, and now select the previous record in the ListView again, all of the RadioButtons for that ListView item will be unchecked. If I move up and down through the ListView long enough, every RadioButton, and the underlying Boolean values, will be set to false.

Model code:

```
 public class Model
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOne { get; set; }
    public bool IsTwo { get; set; }
    public bool IsThree { get; set; }
 }
```

ViewModel code:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _selectedModel;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public List<Model> ModelList { get; set; }

    public Model SelectedModel
    {
        get { return _selectedModel; }
        set
        {
            _selectedModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ModelList = new List<Model>();
        ModelList.Add(new Model() {Name = "Florida"});
        ModelList.Add(new Model() {Name = "Texas"});
        ModelList.Add(new Model() {Name = "Arizona"});
        ModelList.Add(new Model() {Name = "Washington"});
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

And finally, the XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelList}" 
              SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedModel}"  
              DisplayMemberPath="Model">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                                Width="100"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsOne" Content="One" Margin="3" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.IsOne}" 
                     GroupName="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.Name}"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsTwo" Content="Two" Margin="3" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.IsTwo}"  
                     GroupName="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.Name}" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsThree" Content="Three" Margin="3" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.IsThree}" 
                     GroupName="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas of what would be causing the binding to behave in the manner?

Thanks,

Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is a known issue that has continued into Framework 4.5. Franklin Chen provided me with a nice little workaround that extends the RadioButton class.

Here is a link to his [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f52254f-959a-45b4-b135-2d62f60d9718/wpf-radiobuttons-in-details-usercontrol-unchecked-when-navigating-through-parent-listview?forum=wpf).

Here is his code. Now just bind to the IsCheckedReal property and everything works.

```
public class RadioButtonExtended : RadioButton
{
    static bool m_bIsChanging = false;

    public RadioButtonExtended()
    {
        this.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(RadioButtonExtended_Checked);
        this.Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(RadioButtonExtended_Unchecked);
    }

    void RadioButtonExtended_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_bIsChanging)
            this.IsCheckedReal = false;
    }

    void RadioButtonExtended_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_bIsChanging)
            this.IsCheckedReal = true;
    }

    public bool? IsCheckedReal
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(IsCheckedRealProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckedRealProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsCheckedReal. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedRealProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckedReal", typeof(bool?), typeof(RadioButtonExtended),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal |
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
    IsCheckedRealChanged));

    public static void IsCheckedRealChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_bIsChanging = true;
        ((RadioButtonExtended)d).IsChecked = (bool)e.NewValue;
        m_bIsChanging = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of `RadioButton`s in each row of your `ListView`, you will need to provide a unique `GroupName` for each set of `RadioButton`s in each row. The only way that I know how to do that is if you add an extra property to the data type class that you are displaying in the `GridView`. It doesn't matter what that value is as long as each item in the collection has a different value.

You can then `Bind` the new item property to the `GroupName` property of each `RadioButton` in the set:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Demo" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" ... />
    <RadioButton Content="Screener" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" ... />
    <RadioButton Content="Vote" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" ... />
    <RadioButton Content="Vote Follow Up" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" ... />
    <RadioButton Content="Named Vote" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" ... />
</StackPanel>
```

I found an article that demonstrates this nicely with XAML examples:

[Grouped RadioButton for WPF Datagrid](http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/grouped-radiobutton-for-wpf-datagrid/)

---

UPDATE >>>

Yep, in your situation, when you have a group of `RadioButton`s in a container panel of some kind, you don't even need to supply a `GroupName` as the Framework does that for us 'under the covers'. I refactored your XAML to use a different `Binding` to see if that made any difference, but it didn't. You've found a bone fide bug there. Here is the XAML that I ended with that still exhibits the same problem:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}" DisplayMemberPath="Model">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsOne" Content="One" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding ModelList/IsOne}" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsTwo" Content="Two" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding ModelList/IsTwo}" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="IsThree" Content="Three" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding ModelList/IsThree}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I removed the unused properties from your code example in your question. I would also suggest that you edit your question with a more accurate description of the problem... although I didn't quite work out the pattern of clicks that it would take to uncheck a `CheckBox`, I could see that it has nothing to do with the third `RadioButton` in particular. It certainly happened on the other two as well.

It might be worth reporting this as a bug on the [Microsoft Connect website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)... perhaps there's an explanation or workaround there already?

Comment: After looking into this further, this still did not solve the problem. To clarify what I previously described, the UserControl that contains these RadioButtons is not in the ListView, it is bound to the currently selected item from the ListView. Still, I have bound the GroupName to a field that is unique to each item in the List that the ListView is bound to. This is very strange behavior.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include a complete minimal code sample that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Sheridan, thanks for the sanity check! I will follow up by reporting this over on the Connect site.